# What does $$ mean in Prototype and what is its equivalent in Jquery

Tags: jquery, prototype

I am migrating an rails application from prototype to Jquery, i am seeing a syntax like

**`var subEl = $$("#items_grid_container")[0]`**

**`subEl.style.height = windowGridContainerEm + "em"`**

I know how to convert the second part to Jquery, but how do i convert

```
var subEl = $$("#items_grid_container")[0]
```

to its equivalent in Jquery.

I tried `$("#items_grid_container")[0]` but it is not working, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In prototype `$$` is used to get the collection through CSS selectors. That would be a comma separated strings. So, I would say it internally uses `document.querySelectorAll("tag/id/class/attributes")`. 
Although id selector returns only one element.

So, jQuery equivalent is just with single `$`:

```
$("#item_grid_container")[0]
```

Will return you the DOM element instead of jQuery object. So, ***jQuery methods cannot be applied on DOM elements*** and vice versa. Only jQuery object can use the jQuery methods. If you need jQuery object then you don't have to add `[0]` in the selector.

So you have to do this :

```
 var el = $("#item_grid_container");

 el.width(thevarwidth);
```

Comment: so is $("#item_grid_container")[0] in Jquery equivalent to $$("#items_grid_container")[0] in prototype?