# jQuery selector with double dollor ($$)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project, in that they have used $$ to select an id/class. I am not sure about this. Can anybody tell me what does this mean. I googled it. But did not get proper answer.

```
$$("#" + idName + "text").setStyle('background', '#000');
```

Comment: I know that $$ in google chrome is the shorthand for `document.querySelectorAll`, but for use in jQuery? I don't think it makes a difference, but I can't substantiate that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Double Dollar Sign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463867/javascript-double-dollar-sign)

Comment: Can you post more JS? Specifically the IIFE arguments?

Comment: @hsz - I don't think it is a duplicate. That question was asking about a variable name with `$$` whereas this looks like a function library usage.

Comment: Thank you all. Now i need to find which js library file uses $$ in my project.

Comment: This could be because the code is using the Prototype library. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004225/what-does-mean-in-prototype-and-what-is-its-equivalent-in-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply some library shorthand. Like jQuery assigns itself variable `$`, some other library may assign `$$` to itself to avoid conflicting with jQuery

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript $ is a valid variable name, as is $$ and $$$. While you see it mostly used with jQuery, this is not unique to jQuery.

As another answer says, the project you're working with likely has a library which has assigned something to $$.

$ can also be used in variable names like this:

```
$foobar
foo$bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `$$("#" + idName + "text")`, the double `$` doesn't make any sense to me but would be error in your code as jQuery shorthand alias is just a single `$` and when you use `$$(selector)` would make no sense.

But obviously you can assign the `$$` or anything that is valid identifier to work with jQuery to make it no-conflict like below:

```
var $$ = jQuery.noConflict();
$$(selector); //now here $$ is jQuery alias with no problem
```

So, I suppose your code is using some library shorthand method jQuery alias as `$$`.